# Crc32 хэширование

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, умные люди!
Подскажите мне, дураку, как crc32 перевести в десятичный вид? Вот так, чтобы выглядело:

```
 IndexFileCRC val="2283049564"
```

Comment: @fedyuha: То есть вы имеете в виду, что у вас есть строка `"ddead1a9"`, а вы хотите получить из неё число типа `int`, равное `0xddead1a9` (или, что то же самое, `3723153833`)? Тогда вам нужно [`Integer.decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29):

    String crc32hexstr = "ddead1a9";
    Integer crc32 = Integer.decode("0x" + crc32hexstr);

Ну или просто [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

    int crc32 = Integer.parseInt(crc32hexstr);

Comment: @fedyuha, [посмотрите](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) в сторону `.nextInt(16)`.

Comment: Ну, если вам один раз надо, проще воспользоваться калькулятором. Под Windows системный калькулятор переведите в режим "Программист", под линуксом попробуйте `bc <<<'ibase=16; DDEAD1A9'`.

Comment: @fedyuha: 0x56d3a77a == 1456711546

Comment: VladD, напиши, пожалуйста, мне почту свою, если можно будет ещё обратится. rad4in.f@mail.ru

Comment: @fedyuha: лучше спрашивать на форуме, тут больше людей. Сегодня мне вечером нечего делать, завтра ещё кому-нибудь.

Comment: Что, я думал, не получается сделать, а ты хорошо разбираешься в этих проверках crc, тебе можно как-то в личку написать? А то здесь, кажется, коментарии ограничены.